# EnumProperty does not support Chinese in dynamic initialization mode

Tags: interface

I created a new workspacetool to display all the files in the folder, but if the file name is Chinese, it will be garbled. my blender version is 2.93.4,  that's my code:

```
def enum_items(self, context):
    items = []

    path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    folder = os.path.join(path, self.preset_name, "")
    files = [(folder, file) for file in os.listdir(folder)]
    id = 0
    for folder, file in files:
        items.append((file, file, "", "", id))

        id = id + 1

    return items

class WallTool(WorkSpaceTool):
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_context_mode = 'OBJECT'

    bl_idname = "my_template.wall"
    bl_label = "wall tool"
    bl_description = (
        "This is a tooltip\n"
        "with multiple lines"
    )
    bl_icon = "ops.generic.select_lasso"

    bl_keymap = (
        ("my_template.wst_wall_op", {"type": 'LEFTMOUSE', "value": 'PRESS'},
        {"properties": []}),
    )

    def draw_settings(context, layout, tool):
        props = tool.operator_properties("my_template.wst_wall_op")
        layout.prop(props, "style")

class WallOperator(Operator):
    bl_idname = "my_template.wst_wall_op"
    bl_label = "Wall SpaceTool Operator"
    bl_options = {'INTERNAL', 'UNDO'}
    preset_name: StringProperty(default="presets\\test")

    style: EnumProperty(name="Style", items=enum_items)
```

The contents of the 'test' folder are:
[image: test folder]

Interface display：
[image: interface display]

If I initialize EnumProperty like this, it will be correct：

```
     style: EnumProperty(name="Style",
                         items=[
                             ("新建文本文档", "新建文本文档", "", "", 0),
                             ("新建文本文档2", "新建文本文档2", "", "", 1),
                         ], default="新建文本文档")
```

Interface display2：
[image: interface display2]

Comment: There's a [warning about using a callback in the docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html?highlight=enumproperty#bpy.props.EnumProperty). Apparently you need to keep a reference to the items alive on the Python side. Maybe try stuffing items into self or something.

Comment: problem solved，items = []
def enum_items(self, context):
    items.clear()，thanks